# Make HTACCESS to not be applied for some subfolders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using this htaccess for my application.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any URL I will type in my browser, if the respective file doesn't exist, it will open the index.php.

The problem is I have many applications like this installed on the same domain.

For example, the root contains an index.php file and a htaccess like above.

I have also, /store, which contains a index.php file and a htaccess like above, too, but when I access /store/something it opens the index.php of root (not the correct /store/index.php

How can I solve this problem (how to make the htaccess of root to not override the htaccess of /store)? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a skip directory rule to skip all the directories:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# skip index.php and some directories
RewriteRule ^(store/|site1/|site2/|index\.php$) - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you received -1... Thank you. It works. +1 from me.

Comment: No idea mate who downvoted your question and my answer without any comment. It was indeed a very valid question with good amount of details in it. +1 to your question for me.